Oracle: Grant select to view of schema2 which references data in schema1 to schema3
I have a problem with grants.
Here is the Situation:
CREATE VIEW SCHEMA2.VIEW as SELECT * from SCHEMA1.TABLE;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA2.VIEW to SCHEMA3;

The Problem is that SCHEMA3 cannot access the view. It gets permission denied.
I dont want to give SCHEMA3 acccess directly to SCHEMA1.
How can I achieve that?

"cannot access" is pretty much useless. What does that exactly mean? Any error? I presume so; which one, then?

Here's a working example; see if it helps.
3 users are involved:

SCOTT owns the table and grants access (select privilege) to MIKE with grant option; without it, MIKE can't grant it further
MIKE is the 2nd user, the one that creates a view and grants select on it (the view) to the 3rd user, KING

1st user:
SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.

SQL> grant select on emp to mike with grant option;

Grant succeeded.

2nd user:
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.

SQL> create or replace view v_se as select * from scott.emp;

View created.

SQL> select count(*) from v_se;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> grant select on v_se to king;

Grant succeeded.

3rd user:
SQL> connect king/cat@orcl
Connected.

SQL> select count(*) from mike.v_se;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

Can the 3rd user select directly from 1st user's table? No:
SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;
select count(*) from scott.emp
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL>


So, yes - the 3rd user (KING) is capable of accessing SCOTT's data, but not directly.

Your answer would be complete if it showed whether or not the king account can use SELECT * FROM scott.emp; because the OP wants to be able to SELECT ... FROM mike.v_se but NOT to be able to SELECT ... FROM scott.emp.
